# How can I implement a gesture-driven horizontal scroll in a scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, menu, scrollview

I want to implement a gesture-driven scroll menu in a scrollview like this:

[image: Gesture-driven]

If a add button on the scrollview. I can't scroll; it just bounces back.

So do you know how to implement such a horizontal menu?
Especially the gesture/animation is a problem for me!

Comment: I think you just need to adjust scrollView's contentSize

Comment: I have issues with the pangesture. Could anyone write some code?